# CSS uneven div positioning

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to position a div according to the picture:

[image]

I'm successful so far by using Bootstrap's `row` class and using `z-index` in my CSS. But when I resize the browser, it's not responsive, it just floats off the right side of the page. By the way, I'm using `position: absolute` (I read online that I have to use this in order to make use of `z-index`). Is there any other more elegant way to do this? I want it to be responsive but can't seem to find any other workaround than the wonky one I implemented.

Code:

```css
#div2 {
  float: inherit;
  position: absolute;
  top: inherit;
  left: 60%;
  width: 320px;
  height: 1290px;
  z-index: 5;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="div-container">
    <div class="row">
      <div id="div1">
        <p>Div 1</p>
      </div>
      <div id="div2" align='center'>
        <p>Div 2</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div id="div3">
        <p>Div 3</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please share the code that you have used.

Comment: @ManojKumar Sorry I forgot. Added it just now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make use of the nested rows inside a column. See here - [**Bootstrap Nesting**](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/#nesting). Ignore the CSS here as it is for snippet styling and height is used for ignoring the content.

```css
.B {
  min-height: 130px;
  background: #393276;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.A {
  min-height: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  background: #393276;
}

.C {
  min-height: 250px;
  background: #393276;
}

div {
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 32px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<div class="container mt-4">
  <div class="row">
  
    <!-- First Column -->
    <div class="col-sm-6">

      <!--Rows nested inside a column-->
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
          <div class="A">A</div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
          <div class="B">B</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <!-- Second Column -->

    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="C">C</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hmmm I think this is a better answer, still maintains responsiveness. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have used [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) to keep responsive design and some margin positioning to keep the formation together.

```css
.container{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 150px;
}
.div1, .div3{
  margin-right: 5px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
.div2{
  margin-right: 5px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 110px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="div1"> div1 </div>
<div class="div2"> div2 </div>
  <br/>
<div class="div3" style="margin-top: -55px;"> div 3 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, I just added the code I used above. Will your answer work with it?

Comment: @LeeM it's the same, all you need to do is just change the class names to whatever you want..

Comment: @LeeM Updated as you wish.